# Why won't spyder open from different environments in Anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I have several environments in Anaconda:

[image]

And I have spyder installed in one of them:

[image]

However, when I try to launch it from the Navigator it starts to load:
[image]

But nothing happens. I even tried from the console but still nothing:
[image]

I have tried:

```
activate MachineLearning

conda update spyder

conda uninstall spyder

conda install spyder
```

But still no success.

Any ideas - the only solution is to install everything in base but that defeats the purpose of different environments.

Comment: (*Spyder developer here*) Did you use pip to install/update Spyder or any other package while using Anaconda?

Comment: My apologies but I can't remember. Is there a way that I can start from scratch?

Comment: The only way to reinstall Anaconda again. The thing is if you installed `pyqt5` with pip at some point, then you broke Anaconda.

Comment: so even if I re-install it it wont work?
All I want is to install tensor flow

Comment: It should work after a reinstall but only if you install tensorflow with conda and not with pip

Comment: you typed that you tried:  activate MachineLearning but the command should have been source activate MachineLearning

Comment: @jmh, you only need source on Linux... you can see from the OP's command prompt that he's on Windows.

Comment: my bad. thanks.  you also source on a mac which i'm on.

Comment: ok I reset back to factory settings.

How would I then use tensorflow with spyder?